# Relationship between autocorrelation function and wavelet coefficient

Tags: random-variables, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, wavelets, random-functions

the autocorrelation function can be represented using the spectral density in Fourier space. Is there a similar relationship between the autocorrelation function and the coefficient in the wavelet space?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\inprod}[2]{\left\langle{#1}\,|\,{#2}\right\rangle}$
$\newcommand{\eqd}{\triangleq}$
$\newcommand{\setn}[1]{{\left\{{#1}\right\}}}$
$\newcommand{\setu}{\cup}$
$\newcommand{\brp}[1]{{\left(#1\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\brbl}[1]{\left\{#1\right.}$
$\newcommand{\brb}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}$
$\newcommand{\brs}[1]{\left[#1\right]}$
$\newcommand{\setR}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\setC}{\mathbb{C}}$
$\newcommand{\setX}{\mathsf{X}}$
$\newcommand{\opF}{\mathbb{F}}$
$\newcommand{\opW}{\mathbb{W}}$
As you said, the [*auto-correlation function*](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0070484686&pg=PA216) $R_{xx}(t,u)\eqd E\brs{x(t+u)x^{\ast}(t)}$ is simply a "*function*" (a [mapping](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0387901256&pg=PA10) from one set $\mathsf{X}$ to another/same set $\mathsf{Y}$). If $x(t)$ is *stationary*, this definition can be simplified to $R_{xx}(u)\eqd E\brs{x(u)x^{\ast}(0)}$. For a very wide class of functions on $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$, we can use the *Fourier Transform* $\opF$ (transform—a special class of functions often called *operators* that [map](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0817646868&pg=PA42) from one [vector space](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0817641742&pg=PA40) to another/same vector space). When we use the operator $\opF$ to map the vector $R_{xx}(u)$ to a new vector $S_{xx}(\omega)\eqd \opF R_{xx}(u)$, $S_{xx}(\omega)$ is often called the *spectral density* of $x$, or the *power spectral density* (PSD) of $x$.

Of course $\mathbb{F}$ is not the only transform (vector space mapping) that can be applied to $R_{xx}(u)$—*any* transform that operates over the domain used by $R_{xx}(u)$ could be used. Example transforms include the *Laplace Transform* (a generalization of the Fourier Transform), *B-spline* transform**s** (note on "s": there are an infinite number of B-splines), and of course Wavelet Transform**s**. Likewise if $R_{xx}$ was discrete (e.g. "$R_{xx}(m)$") rather than continuous, transforms might include the DFT/FFT, Z-transform, and Hadamard Transform.

But to me, your question is not just *if* the wavelet transform $\opW$ can be applied to $R_{xx}$; it is more like, "**Can $\opW$ be applied in *like manner* as $\opF$ and get a *like manner* usefulness?**" That is, just as the "Power Spectral Density" can be used to calculate the "*power*" (or something resembling it) in the "spectrum" of $\opF$, **can the projection $\opW R_{xx}$ of $R_{xx}$ also be used to calculate power** (or something resembling it)?

Here, "*spectrum*" is defined as the *projection coefficients*/"[*Fourier coefficients*](https://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0127729550&pg=PA6)" $G(\omega)$ of $\mathbb{F}$
$$\brb{\begin{align*}
  G(\omega)
    &\eqd \brs{\opF R_{xx}(t)}(\omega)
     \eqd\inprod{R_{xx}(t)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{i\omega t}}
     \eqd \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t\in\setR}R_{xx}(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt
  \\&\text{of $R_{xx}$ onto the basis $\setn{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{i\omega t} | \omega\in\mathbb{R}}$ and $\opW R_{xx}$}
  \\
  H(a,b)
    &\eqd \brs{\mathbb{W}R_{xx}}(a,b)
     \eqd \inprod{R_{xx}(t)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\psi\left(\frac{\omega-b}{a}\right)}
     \eqd \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{t\in\setR} R_{xx}(t)\psi\left(\frac{\omega-b}{a}\right)
\end{align*}}$$
is the projection of $R_{xx}$ onto whatever wavelet basis $\{\psi\}$ (e.g. Haar, Daubechies-$p$, [Symmlets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0898712742)-$p$) is used in the definition of wavelet transform $\mathbb{W}$.

The answer is "Yes" and is demonstrated by the [Plancherel Formula](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0817646868&pg=PA34) or more generally by [Parseval's Identity](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0486402517&pg=PA154) in any Hilbert Space:
$$\left\lVert R_{xx}(t) \right\rVert^2 = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{z}}\left|\left\langle R_{xx}(t),\phi_n(t)\right\rangle\right|^2$$
where the [sequence](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0521842832&pg=PA24) $\{\phi_n(t)\}$ is any [*orthonormal* basis](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0127729550&pg=PA6) (Fourier, Wavelet, Hadamard, etc.) for the space.

The term “spectral power” is arguably a bit of an oxymoron because “spectral” deals with leaving the time-domain for an alternate (call it "frequency" if you wish) domain$\ldots$ howbeit the concept of power is solidly founded on the concept of time in that power = energy per time. However, Plancherel/Parseval demonstrate that "power" $\left\lVert R_{xx}(t) \right\rVert^2$ in time can also be calculated from any Hilbert Space transform that is constructed over an orthonormal basis.